# Acl in CakePHP - Removing this functionality

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, acl

I built a project with Acl enabled - I used the CakePHP tutorial on their website to do this.
However, the project no longer needs this functionality.

I've removed all reference of Acl and Aco in my controllers, models and views (if fact I did the tutorial in reverse to remove everything) and I then deleted the three database tables that were generated in this process.

However, I still get the error:

```
Error: Database table acos for model Aco was not found.
```

On all of my controllers.

Did the acl baking process add some files I don't know about? How do I get rid of this functionality?

Comment: Have you removed them from app_controller?

Comment: yeah... that was my first hit ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try emptying your `app/tmp/cache`. Model relations may be caches there. After that, `grep` through your `app` directory for references to `Aco` and `Aro`. You may have missed one.

**Edit**: Also, make sure that your `Auth` component does not set `Auth->authorize` to `actions` (which uses ACL) but something else appropriate. See [Auth::authorize](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1275/authorize) in the CakePHP manual.

Comment: I emptied the cache and still had the issue but I found the Acl Component inside the app_controller so I removed it and I get: `Could not find AclComponent. Please include Acl in Controller::$components.` I still need to use Auth for administrative login, are these two components intrinsically linked somehow?

Comment: They can be linked, yes. See my edit. Also, remember to re-empty the cache after making changes.

Comment: that was the answer, I had Auth->authorize in my app_controller. You, sir, are a lifesaver! Thank you!